# Search List for an item and get the entire entry with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<Coord>` that contains lots if entries with elements called `Segment, startX, startY, endX, endY.`

Question is: when I have a certain segment, I would like to search the `List` for it, and when I find it, copy the entire entry including `segment, startx, starty`.. to a new list. If possible I'd like to use LINQ expression.

Class that adds the entries:

```
public class Coord
{
    public string Segment { get; set; }
    public double startX { get; set; }
    public double startY { get; set; }
    public double endX { get; set; }
    public double endY { get; set; }
    public string Naziv { get; set; }
}
```

So if I have a certain segmet value, I'd like to search the `List<Coord>` for it, and when I find it, copy the corresponding coordinates and segment (the entire index) to a new `List`.

Comment: we dont know what u mean. A list of what things, what 'entries', what 'elements', whats a 'segment'. Show a simple example

Comment: This is not easy to picture without at least some code that shows how an element or an entry look.

Comment: @pm100 added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given a `Coord needle` and a `List<Coord> haystack`, you would do `var myNewList = haystack.Where(c -> c.Segment == needle.segment).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
string lookedSegment = ...
List<Coord> newList = originalList.Where((c) => c.Segment == lookedSegment).ToList();
```

Above code would create a new list with current entries on it, if you need new entries you would clone them with following code:

```
List<Coord> newList = originalList.Where((c) => c.Segment = lookedSegment)
                                  .Select((c) => new Coord {
                                     Segment = c.Segment,
                                     startX = c.startX,
                                     startY = c.startY,
                                     endX = c.endX,
                                     endY = c.endY,
                                     Naziv = c.Naziv
                                  })
                                  .ToList();
```